# Celery worker getting crashed on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I am working on a `Django` project which I have pushed on `Heroku`, for background tasking I have used `Celery`. Although Celery works fine locally, but on the Heroku server I have observed that celery worker is getting crashed. I have set `CLOUDAMQP_URL` properly in `settings.py` and configured worker configuration in `Procfile`, but still worker is getting crashed.

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn my_django_app.wsgi --log-file -
worker: python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

**Settings.py**

```
...
# Celery
BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CLOUDAMQP_URL", "django://")
#CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = 100
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER="json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER="json"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp://"
```

**Logs**

```
2019-08-05T15:03:51.296563+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-08-05T15:04:05.370900+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info`
2019-08-05T15:04:06.173210+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-08-05T15:04:09.067794+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-08-05T15:04:08.778426+00:00 app[worker.1]: Unknown command: 'celery'
2019-08-05T15:04:08.778447+00:00 app[worker.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2019-08-05T15:04:09.048404+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_django_app.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: In your manage.py, when you referred to your celery path, did you entered the full path?
Example: /opt/app/venv/bin/celery not just "celery"

Comment: @IgorServulo Hello, I have added code in `manage.py`, Please have a look at updated post.

Comment: That's it, neither your heroku server can't find a PATH for the keyword celery when you execute it with `execute_from_command_line` or celery isn't installed on heroku. Have you entered on your config file that the app needs celery? I saw that you specify manage.py as the worker, but it should be defined with something like that: `worker: celery worker --app=tasks.app`.

Comment: @IgorServulo Do I need to write `worker: celery worker --app=tasks.app` in `Procfile`

Comment: @IgorServulo I have made following changes in `Procfile` but same error persists `web: gunicorn resume_filter_tool.wsgi --log-file -`, `worker: celery worker -A tasks.app -l info`, `worker: python manage.py celery worker -l info`

Comment: The `tasks.app` file was an example. You should set this parameter as your celery file.

Comment: @IgorServulo Hello, at below link you can see directory structure of the project and all relevant files code. It will be helpful, If you have a look at it once.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zhvlowcfi3pz524/AABzP1kj2xRBixfXMLA6uhdRa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes in `Procfile` and error got resolved

```
web: gunicorn my_django_app.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A my_django_app worker -l info
```